# Pattern for a specific ending of letters (words)

Tags: angular, regex, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to do the following:
Only letters and numbers passed in the input, and also, at the end of the line, there were always letters/words: xls, xslx, json, xml.

Currently using this pattern:

```js
Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a non-capturing group to match any mentioned words at the end.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:xls|xlsx|json|xml)$
```

[Demo @ Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/96BCwX/2)